# Launch CallLog activity in android using Intent

Tags: android

I'm able to launch the Call Log activity using intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI);
startActivity(intent);
```

But on selecting any Log (incoming, Outgoing or missed ) from Call Log activity it will initiate a call.

But according to my requirement i want to use  above intent using action `Intent.ACTION_PICK` and `startActivityForResult(intent)`.

please share any idea to do the same.

Comment: so u are going correct, What is the issue?

Comment: i want to get the selected call log data back in my activity that we get the same from contact in onActivityResult().

Comment: override `onActivityResult()` method